# Parallel testing in py.test

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Is there any way to use parallel/ concurrent testing in py test? If not can any one please recommend good solution to do parallel testing of several test cases in python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytest actually has plugin called [pytest-xdist](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-xdist/), which allows you to parallelize test runs.

Once you install that plugin, you can run the tests using multiple processes, for instance on 4 CPUs:

```
pytest -n 4
```

You might need to adapt the tests for them to be parallelization-friendly, but if they are already well isolated, this should just work!

Comment: I use Pycharm IDE. Can you please tell me how to import this command in pycharm?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use PyCharm, but I'm sure there is a way to add the dependency to your project. Looking quickly I found https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/managing-dependencies.html, which should at least get you started in the right direction!